# Personal HTML Form to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking into the webpage (http://ordrespontane.blogspot.com/2018/01/html-form-to-google-sheet.html) about how to connect google sheets to a web form not made by google.  I followed the instructions, however, it seems to be to no avail to me.  Has anyone else used it and become successful?  I also notice that my name and info, once inserted into the form, does not go away.   Is that normal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxRtG9fv7vE14yZR8_46YQrqC76wkDvHqT88ArBmeriPlPc4aB6/exec">
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:200px"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:200px"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p><span id="myConf">This is where the confirmation message will appear after submission.</span></p>





<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // References:
    var $form = $('#myForm');
    var $conf = $('#myConf');
    var $subm = $('#mySubmit');
    var $impt = $form.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
 // Submit function:
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
      // On success, clear all inputs;
            $impt.val('').attr('value','').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
   // Write a confirmation message:
            $conf.html("Submitted!");
   // Disable the submit button:
            $subm.prop('disabled', true);
        },'json');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add this code: http://ordrespontane.blogspot.com/2018/01/html-form-to-google-sheet.html#file-form-gs ?

Comment: Take a look [at this blogspot](https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/). It's primarliy for users of Jekyll site generator, but I think it should work for any kind of webpage (I've used it succesfully myself).

Comment: I tried it and it works.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is mechanism preventing your form from being sent. Browser won't let you do HTTP request to other site than the one the site was loaded from. I'm guessing you are testing it on html page on your PC.

To allow request to [script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxRtG9fv7vE14yZR8_46YQrqC76wkDvHqT88ArBmeriPlPc4aB6/exec)
you have to add HTTP header webserver for this particular page

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://script.google.com
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or you can use browser plugin to do this for you (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)).

Comment: Thank you so much for  your comment! I appreciate it.